# Unable to encode/decode pprint output

Tags: python, django, unicode, formatting

This question is based on a side-effect of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10881326/257972).

My `.py` files are all have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` encoding definer on the first line, like my `api.py`

As I mention on the related question, I use `HttpResponse` to return the api documentation. Since I defined encoding by:

```
HttpResponse(cy_content, content_type='text/plain; charset=utf-8')
```

Everything is ok, and when I call my API service, there are no encoding problems except *the string formed from a dictionary by pprint*

Since I am using Turkish characters in some values in my dict, pprint converts them to `unichr` equivalents, like:

```
API_STATUS = {
    1: 'müşteri',
    2: 'some other status message'
}

my_str = 'Here is the documentation part that contains Turkish chars like işüğçö'
my_str += pprint.pformat(API_STATUS, indent=4, width=1)
return HttpRespopnse(my_str, content_type='text/plain; charset=utf-8')
```

And my plain text output is like:

```
Here is the documentation part that contains Turkish chars like işüğçö

{
    1: 'm\xc3\xbc\xc5\x9fteri',
    2: 'some other status message'
}
```

I try to decode or encode pprint output to different encodings, with no success... What is the best practice to overcome this problem

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`pprint` appears to use `repr` by default, you can work around this by overriding [`PrettyPrinter.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter.format):

```
# coding=utf8

import pprint

class MyPrettyPrinter(pprint.PrettyPrinter):
    def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
        if isinstance(object, unicode):
            return (object.encode('utf8'), True, False)
        return pprint.PrettyPrinter.format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)


d = {'foo': u'işüğçö'}

pprint.pprint(d)              # {'foo': u'i\u015f\xfc\u011f\xe7\xf6'}
MyPrettyPrinter().pprint(d)   # {'foo': işüğçö}
```

Comment: if, like me, you're trying to use this with `pformat` (instead of pprint) and send the resulting string to a templating engine such as `jinja2`, it will give you a `UnicodeDecodeError`, which you can solve by calling (in the terms of this answer) `unicode(MyPrettyPrinter().pformat(d), 'utf-8')`.

Comment: Can you wrap your pprint with format set option to PyPI, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should use unicode strings instead of 8-bit ones:

```
API_STATUS = {
    1: u'müşteri',
    2: u'some other status message'
}

my_str = u'Here is the documentation part that contains Turkish chars like işüğçö'
my_str += pprint.pformat(API_STATUS, indent=4, width=1)
```

The `pprint` module is designed to print out all possible kind of nested structure in a readable way. To do that it will print the objects representation rather then convert it to a string, so you'll end up with the escape syntax wheather you use unicode strings or not. But if you're using unicode in your document, then you really should be using unicode literals!

Anyway, [thg435 has given you a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10883893/1350899) how to change this behaviour of pformat.

Comment: Are normal (non unicode) strings known as binary strings? I thought they were ascii strings

Comment: i tried that too, i also tried django's `smart_str`, `smart_unicode` and soe other methods... When i use unicode string like `u'müşteri`, what i get is `u'm\xfc\u015fteri'`

Comment: @FallenAngel - that is the representation for the unicode string which is generated by pformat, I see that your problem is a little different then i thought... I'll check this again...

Comment: @jdi: In python2, `str` type is a sequence of bytes.

Comment: @jdi - In python < 3 they're most commonly called 8-bit strings, i used the wrong term here, I usually don't care so much about this as it won't matter with python3 anymore...