# python pprint: how to output utf8 characters?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with { 'utf8 char' : number }. pprint() would treat the utf8 as a byte array and output hex values. Is it possible to tell it to print it as string so that the console can render UTF8 text?

Comment: *The `pprint` module provides a capability to “pretty-print” arbitrary Python data structures in a form which can be used as input to the interpreter.*

Comment: @Blender are you saying it's impossible?

Comment: It is possible. Google to the rescue! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883399/unable-to-encode-decode-pprint-output

Comment: @lang2: That's what the default `pprint` module does. You'd have to change some stuff in order for it to work.