# Displaying cyrillic symbols in python

Tags: python, encoding, cyrillic

Let's say I have a content in Russian in a variable:

```
msg = '<some russian text here>'
print msg
```

gives me correct value but

```
print [msg]
```

gives me this:

```
['\xd0\x9f\xd0\xa4 "\xd0\x9a\xd0\xa2\xd0\x9f-\xd0\xa3\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb" (\xd0\x97\xd0\x90\xd0\x9e)']
```

How do I keep cyrillic symbols in list?

Comment: Python containers use `repr()` to represent contained values; the output is meant for debug purposes *only*. Do you *have* to produce that output with `'` quotes and the square brackets for a list object?

Comment: @qarma: but this is not a unicode value. It is a **byte string**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters details! I'm talking about what OP wants, no what he asks for :P

Comment: @qarma: you'll need to address that issue in your post though, as the solution you link to only works for `unicode` objects.

Comment: @zjor what version of Python do you target?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that directly, but you can get very close with `pprint`.

There is example code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10883893/705086

It covers unicode type only, but can easily be adapted to utf-8 encoded str/bytes as in OP.

Ideally pprint should maintain the invariant that formatted/printed PDO is a valid Python expression. Linked code can be hacked to maintain this invariant just as well.

You can monkey-path `pprint` module to maintain this invariant:

```
import functools, pprint

def escape(s):
    lead = ""
    if isinstance(s, unicode):
        s = s.encode("utf-8")
        lead = "u"
    return "%s\"%s\"" % (lead, s.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\"", "\\\""))

def patched(f):
    if hasattr(f, "_already_patched"):
        return f

    @functools.wraps(f)
    def sub(object, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if isinstance(object, basestring):
                return escape(object), True, False
        except Exception:
            pass
        return f(object, *args, **kwargs)

    sub._already_patched = True
    return sub

pprint._safe_repr = patched(pprint._safe_repr)

pprint.pprint([u"\N{EURO SIGN}", u"\N{EURO SIGN}".encode("utf-8")])
[u"€", "€"]
```