# Problems parsing \xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe etc

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters

I am reading some data from the database having data in various languages, one of them being Russian. When I try to read the text, the string reads as follows:

```
('\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82 \xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b \xd0\xb5\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe \xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9\xd1\x87\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81 \xd0\xb8 \xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb4\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5! \xd0\xa0\xd0\xb0\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x8b \xd0\xb5\xd1\x89\xd1\x91 \xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb1\xd1\x8f \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x8f\xd0\xb2\xd1\x8f\xd1\x82. \xd1\x8d\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb5\xd1\x89\xd1\x91 \xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x87\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe!',)
```

So if I now write my code as:

```
import pprint

class MyPrettyPrinter(pprint.PrettyPrinter):
    def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
        if isinstance(object, unicode):
            return (object.encode('utf8'), True, False)
        return pprint.PrettyPrinter.format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)

a = ('\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82 \xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b \xd0\xb5\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe \xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9\xd1\x87\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81 \xd0\xb8 \xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb4\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5! \xd0\xa0\xd0\xb0\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x8b \xd0\xb5\xd1\x89\xd1\x91 \xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb1\xd1\x8f \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x8f\xd0\xb2\xd1\x8f\xd1\x82. \xd1\x8d\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb5\xd1\x89\xd1\x91 \xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x87\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe!',)

MyPrettyPrinter().pprint(a)
```

The output is:

```
('\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82 \xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b \xd0\xb5\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe \xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9\xd1\x87\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81 \xd0\xb8 \xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb4\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5! \xd0\xa0\xd0\xb0\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x8b \xd0\xb5\xd1\x89\xd1\x91 \xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb1\xd1\x8f \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x8f\xd0\xb2\xd1\x8f\xd1\x82. \xd1\x8d\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb5\xd1\x89\xd1\x91 \xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x87\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe!',)
```

I would like to convert this text back to ASCII. I have tried the `PrettyPrinter` method explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883399/unable-to-encode-decode-pprint-output/10883893#10883893), but this method prints the string. I would like to capture this "fixed" string in ASCII/utf-8 format (the real Russian text, not the text with slashes in it) and store it in a list and I am unable to figure out how to do that. 
Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

EDIT:

[image]

This is the string that I have, I tried converting it into unicode but it doesn't have any affect at all.

Comment: "I would like to convert this text back to ASCII." You cannot have Russian text in ASCII.

Comment: understood, but can I have it in the real Russian format? Something that doesn't have slashes? Or is there a way to ignore such text?

Comment: It **is** in real Russian "format" (UTF-8 to be precise). It's just not printed as such in this case. Have you actually used those strings anywhere, or are you stuck on these tuples?

Comment: For now I am just stuck on using these tuples. I would be more than happy to ignore these strings too, is there a way to do that?

Comment: The strings are absolutely correct. Have you used them for anything? Saved into a file? Displayed in a browser? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If you print a container object like tuples, every element in it will be converted to its `repr()` string form, which is hexadecimal escapes for byte values outside displayable ASCII characters for strings.  It is done that way, so the programmer can see what the values actually contain, without a terminal interpreting it according to some encoding.  Assuming terminals don't mess with ASCII.

```
print a[0]
# -> вот вы его сейчас и оправдываете! Рашисты ещё себя проявят. это ещё даже не начало!
```

So if your terminal uses UTF-8 then simply take the value out of the tuple and print it.  Otherwise you may want to *decode* the string with UTF-8 into a `unicode` object before processing it further.

Comment: Please see the edit, may be it will clarify things further. I want the string returned into an object, not printed to the console. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: That is a quite substantial change to the question.  So you don't have a tuple with a string but a string with the `repr()` form of a tuple with a string.  How did you end up with this?

Anyway, this can be turned into a tuple with a string with the `ast.literal_eval()` function.  But you should really try to fix this problem at the other end, where this is written into the database.