# Write UTF-8 strings to file with pprint

Tags: python, file, utf-8, stream, pprint

I would like to write dictionaries with UTF-8 strings to a file. I saw [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883399/unable-to-encode-decode-pprint-output) thread about printing utf-8 strings with pprint, and tried to modify the code seen there like this

```
MyPrettyPrinter().pprint(dict, stream=f)
```

but it is not working. I have no experience in classes in python, so I have no idea what to redefine in the pprint library.

Comment: Sorry I somehow missed your link I can't see properly or the hyperlinks here aren't bright enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
MyPrettyPrinter(stream=f).pprint(d)
```