# How to write dict into file with characters other than English letters in python 2.7.8?

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is the simple example:

```
test = {'location': '北京', 'country': '中国'}  # the values are Chinese.
```

In file test.log:

```
{'location': '北京', 'country': '中国'}
```

In python 2.7.8, when I need to output data, I use str() method.

```
file_out = open('test.log', 'w')
file_out.write(str(test))
file_out.close()
```

`str()` method does not work when dict contains other characters.  I know in python2 the default is ASCII, and this does not support Chinese.

My questions is that how can I output dict into files? Someone mentioned Json package for me, but I do not how to use.

Comment: What do you mean "str() method does not work"?

Comment: str() method will encode test with ASCII. The output will be something like this: `{'country': '\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd', 'location': '\xe5\x8c\x97\xe4\xba\xac'}`  instead of `{'location': '北京', 'country': '中国'}`.

Comment: I have a similar problem within a different context, I have problems in printing the dictionary itself on HttpResponse. [Here is my problem and solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883399/unable-to-encode-decode-pprint-output) . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
ori_test = {'location': '北京', 'country': '中国'}
test = dict([(unicode(k, "utf-8"), unicode(v, "utf-8")) for k, v in ori_test.items()])

my_dict = json.dumps(test, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
print my_dict
# then write my_dict to the local file as you want
```

And this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence) could be helpful for you.

Comment: Here in my situation, test is dict type, not string type. I tried to run your code by removing u and the double quotes, and then error occurs. 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128).

Comment: It should be `test = {u'location': u'北京', u'country': u'中国'}`

Comment: This works. But when the value of location generates dynamically, how to add u before the value to declare unicode encoding? @tripleee

Comment: Whatever generates the string should convert it to a Unicode string before returning it.  Sounds like maybe you should read http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: @Ray I think you have to convert it one by one.

Comment: It does what you apparently want it to do but it's not a very comprehensive answer for this particular question.  The code which generates the values needs to return Unicode strings (and generally, you should make all of your code use Unicode strings).  Then the JSON part will trivially work.

Comment: @m170897017 I tried to run your code on both windows and Linux platform. but it fails at this line: `test = dict([(unicode(k), unicode(v)) for k, v in ori_test.items()])`. Error message is "'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)". :(

Comment: @m170897017 What about this method: `import json
ori_test = {'location': '北京', 'country': '中国'}
my_dict = json.dumps(ori_test, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf-8')
print my_dict` This works well!

Comment: @Ray After checking the source code of json.dumps, I found that key point here is ensure_ascii=False. In your method, without encoding='utf-8' it will still work, since default value of encoding is 'utf-8'. Anyway, this is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

The code which populates this structure should produce Unicode strings (Python 2 `u"..."` strings), not byte strings (Python 2 "..." strings).  See 
http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html for a good introduction to the pertinent differences between these two data types.

Building on (an earlier version of) m170897017's answer;

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
test = {u'location': u'北京', u'country': u'中国'}
my_json = json.dumps(test, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
print my_json
```

If you have code which programmatically populates the `location` field, make it populate it with a Unicode string.  For example, if you read UTF-8 data from somewhere, `decode()` it before putting it there.

```
def update_location ():
    location = '北京'
    return location.decode('utf-8')

test['location'] = update_location()
```

You could use other serialization formats besides JSON, including the `str()` representation of the Python structure, but JSON is standard, well-defined, and well-documented.  It requires all strings to be UTF-8, so it works trivially for non-English strings.

Python2 works internally with either byte strings or Unicode strings, but in this scenario, Unicode strings should be emphatically recommended, and will be the only sensible choice if/when you move to Python3.  Convert everything to Unicode as soon as you can and convert (back?) to an external representation (e.g. UTF-8) only when you have to.

Comment: Ack contribution by @m170897017

Comment: Thanks for your useful link. It helps me have a better understanding of unicode and byte string. I will throughly read it. But in my situation, I want to use utf-8 encoding to easily identify the value. Unicode is hard to read.

Comment: @tripleee Your last sentence is valuable and helpful to avoid many pitfalls! Thanks!